# How to do complex regular expressions in list.files in R

Tags: regex, r

I cannot find any example on how to use the `pattern=` parameter in `list.files` for more complex operations.

I would like to get all the files that include either *'XM'* or *'EM'* and are of the *.cvs* type

Can someone please help me.

I was trying something like

`list.files(path='.', pattern="[XM | EM] & csv")`

but it is definitely wrong

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try this:

```
list.files(path='.', pattern="(XM|EM).*\\.csv$")
```

Comment: Thanks, but that line does not work. What worked for me is this line:

`list.files(path='.', pattern="(XM|EM).*\\.csv$")`

There was some problem with escaping the _dot_ with only one `\`

Comment: If Tom edits his answer correctly with the double escape you should accept that as an answer.

If you want to use perl compatible regex syntax you can use dir()[grepl("pattern",dir(),perl=TRUE)] or stick with list.files instead of dir but use in the same way.

Comment: I found this to work rather with `[]` squared brackets.